# ng-controller works, ui-router: controller not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I'd like to load a view with template/controller configured in a ui-router state, but the controller doesn't seem to get loaded, no matter what I try, without any error messages.

```
module App {

    var dependencies = [
         "ui.router",
         Controllers
    ]

    function configuration($stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state("test", {
                url: "/test",
                views: {
                    "": { templateUrl: "parentView.html" },
                    "testPartial@" : {
                        templateUrl: "partial.html",
                        controller: <--- see below
                        ...
                    }
                ...
    }
```

What I tried:

```
controller: Controllers.TestController

controller: App.Controllers.TestController

controller: "App.Controllers.TestController"

controller: "App.Controllers.ITestController" (interface)
```

However, if I declare `ng-controller="App.Controllers.TestController as vm"` on my template, everything works flawlessly.

Comment: What is there in `... <-- see below`? You need t0 specify controller in the state configuration, you can also specify controllerAs as well

Comment: Click on [Documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) and search for phrase "each view in views can set up its own templates" and look at the example below that. For controller name, you just need to state the name like "chillCtrl" in .controller("chillCtrl"). Make sure chillCtrl is already defined or use lazyloading.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#user-content-controllers+

Comment: @PSL Yes, I've read the documentation many times and tried every possible way, however nothing seems to work.

Comment: @user013948 I tried with just the controller name (without modules path), it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try console.log(Controllers, App, App.Controllers) and what does it say?

Comment: @user013948 Much stuff (from my real app, not pseudo names like above): http://pastebin.com/3jD4Eh9Z (I printed out: console.log(SetupGroups.SetupGroupTableController, SetupGroups, App))

Answer (score 0):

Given what works on ng-controller, *controller: "App.Controllers.TestController"* is guaranteed to work.

The isse is with the *as vm* portion being missing. You can overcome that by putting the controller on the scope: https://youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E&hd=1